# Mutating elements of a list in Prolog

Tags: list, random, prolog

I am supposed to write a rule in SWI Prolog, which takes a list of characters as input and then replaces each letter by a random other character with a probability of 0.01.

Example:

```
?- mutate([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],MutatedList).
MutatedList = [a,b,c,a,e,f,g].
```

Can anyone tell me how that could be implemented? I am totally clueless so far about how this could work out in Prolog.

Thanks to anyone who can help!^^

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy. You can use `maplist/3` to relate the elements of the lists in a pairwise way. (Take a look at [some of my notes on `maplist/3`](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/maplist/maplist_3_examples.md)].

For each pair `[InputItem,OutputItem]` sampled from `[InputList,OutputList]`, `maplist/3` will call a predicate, call it `choose(InputItem,OutputItem)`.

That predicate will relate `InputItem` to the same value, `InputItem` or to a randomly chosen character (atom of length 1), which can be generated by selecting it randomly from a list of characters. The choice on whether to perform mutation can be made using [`random_float/0`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f(random_float/0)) for example.

Of course, `choose(InputItem,OutputItem)` is not really a predicate (it is just called that way, both in name at runtime), as it does not behave "predicatly" at all, i.e. it will have different outcomes depending on the time of day. It's an Oracle getting information from a magic reservoir. But that's okay.

Now you are all set. Not more than 4 lines!